# Wireshark not capturing packets when applying "tcp and host 157.240.23.35" (157.240.23.35= ip address of facebook)

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet, packet-sniffers, packet-capture

I am trying to Capture all TCP traffic to/from Facebook, during the time when i log in to my Facebook account using this "tcp and host 157.240.23.35" capture filter, but it is not capturing any packets.

I found the ip address of Facebook on cmd using "ping facebook.com".

I even tried disabling and enabling the promiscous mode both but still no packets. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has many thousands of IP addresses, and many subnets. You will not be able to do a simple capture on a single IP address, nor even on a single subnet.

Comment: https://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~marsic/books/CN/projects/wireshark/ws-project-1.html

Comment: i am trying to do this assigment

Comment: how should i do it then

Comment: I know how to run wireshark. And the answer to your question, you capture port 443 and only have traffic running to them.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook IP address rage is available here: https://gist.github.com/Whitexp/9591384

You can use range command in Wireshark instead of single IP address.

**For example::**  `ip.addr==31.13.24.0/21 || ip.addr == 31.13.64.0/19`

[image]

Since the list contains many subnets, I have shown only two. You can find the updated subnets on internet and modify the filter accordingly.

**For example::**   `ip.addr==31.13.24.0/21 || ip.addr == 31.13.64.0/19 || ip.addr == (IP address range 3) || ip.addr == (IP address range 4)`